# Adding attributes from polygons to a different layer with different polygons in r

Tags: r, gis, polygon, shapes, geo

I have been trying to make a geo process that seems a bit of hard.  I have two shapes layers  with different geometry, one with data and that other whiteout.

I am trying to extract the data from one layer and add it proportionally with the area to the other layer.  Example ....

[Layer 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0odiQ.jpg)

[Layer 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAEsa.jpg)

The shapes seem very similar but the polygons are different.  One has data about the total population in a given area. I would like to extract that information proportionally and add it to the other layer (imagine that the second layer has a polygon that fits in one polygons and the half of another one, so I would like to get that population proportionally).

My first approach was converting everything to raster and then extract the data for the pixels of the raster. This works with  some data that I can get means but no with data that I have to sum all the data from the polygons.  I show you this approach:

```
# Lecture of the first layer 
Zonificacion <-  shapefile("Zonificacion.shp")
proj4string(Zonificacion) <- CRS("+init=EPSG:4326")here


# Lecture of the second layer 
zoificacion_2 <- readOGR("marginacion.shp")


###  Transform the first layer in raster

r <- raster(extent(Zonificacion_2)) # creates a raster with the extent of  this layer 
projection(r) <- proj4string(Zonificacion_2) # uses the projection of the shapefile for the raster

res(r)= 0.001 # sets the resolution of the raster to 10 m

r10 <- rasterize(Zonificacion_2, field="IMU2010", r)
plot(r10)

# Extracting the values of the raster to the other layer 

rasValue=extract(r10,Zonificacion, fun= mean)  

#Tranform it to a data frame 
df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(rasValue), nrow=length(rasValue), byrow=T))
names(agebs)[names(agebs) == "CVE_AGEB"] <- "AGEB"
```

I hope you can help me and that I have expressed clear.

Best regards,
Orlando

Comment: Can you share some code, of what you have tried so far? In regards to your data, maybe you can get the information about the population density from a different source? In that case, you would only need one key-column (column which is the same in each data) and then you could left-join them.

Comment: hello @YannikSuhre I will show the code I have

Comment: hello @YannikSuhre   I just posted my first approach.  How I say  I tranform tthe layer in raster to be able to extract the values from each pixel and match them to any other form. 
However, this aproach worked for a kind of data and for other is not possible. 
For example, in the case of population it doest work because ot start to sum all the pixeles (each pixel will have the total population of the  original shape) I can not use an average nither. 
The best will be sum the values of the polygons and not convert any shape to a raster